# https.request() is giving Error: connect ECONREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443

Tags: node.js, express, https

*Hello there,
I'm at my wits end I'm struggling I would like to know where I'm going wrong
I can't seem to get past this error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443 
something tells me it's something small that I'm neglecting but I can't see it.
I read here that it's possible that the is a network overload problem but I have shut everything down except my ngrok to simulate https and the mongodb running yet still no joy. Any and all suggestions appreciated*

```
const https = require('https');

app.get('/auth/instagram', (req, res) => {
  const clientId = process.env.INSTAGRAM_ID;
  const redirectUri = process.env.INSTAGRAM_ID_URI;
  res.redirect(`https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code`);
});
app.get('/auth/instagram/callback', (req, res) => {
  // console.log('this is the code', req.query.code);

  const { code } = req.query;
  console.log('this is the code ', code);
  const redirectURL = `${process.env.BASE_URL}/auth/instagram/callback`;
  const url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token';
  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: {
      client_id: process.env.INSTAGRAM_ID,
      client_secret: process.env.INSTAGRAM_SECRET,
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      redirect_uri: redirectURL,
      code
    },
    json: true,
    url
  };
  console.log('This is that options', options);
  https.request(options, (err, res) => {
    console.log('this is the body', res);
  });
  process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

});
```

Error

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 443
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `PORT 443` for your Node.js Application, because of this port used by the HTTP server for `Secure HTTP or https://` connection. Use a different port address. If you want to use `PORT 443` then install the `Nginx` server and connect your Node.js application in `Reverse Proxy` methodology. You need to install an `SSL Certificate` and bind it into the Nginx Config file if you want to use `https://` for your Node.js Application.

You can also follow this tutorial. Click this
[link](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/)

Comment: Hi there Thanks ...so I tried a couple of different things to get to a solution & still not yet there
instead of using request I decided to try axios  error 400
axios({
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    url,
    body: {
      client_id: process.env.INSTAGRAM_ID,
      client_secret: process.env.INSTAGRAM_SECRET,
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      redirect_uri: redirectUri,
      code
    },
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
});

Comment: regarding your comment ....I'm using ngrok externally to simulate the https
Now I know there is nothing wrong with the code cos I can use it in postman and get good results it just seems that my use of it in the node is not good ...Thank you for your continued insight on this matter

Answer (score -1):

Try setting your options with hostname and path parameters, and remove 'url'.  Other libraries often use `'url' : url` so that is likely the problem.  Node's `https` uses host or hostname and path. See [this](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#httpsgetoptions-callback).

```
  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    hostname: 'api.instagram.com',
    path: '/oauth/access_token',    
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: {
      client_id: process.env.INSTAGRAM_ID,
      client_secret: process.env.INSTAGRAM_SECRET,
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      redirect_uri: redirectURL,
      code
    },
    json: true
  };
```

If you want to use a url, it should be declared as a URL Object, for example:

`const options = new URL('https://abc:xyz@example.com');`

Or you can use a url string.  In the case of a string or a URL Object, you cannot have additional options, so it is not all that useful for your situation.

I'll add that I had this exact same error with a Node GCP Cloud Function, and this fixed it.